# Is it possible to add holes on volumetric clouds in eevee 2.92?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to add a hole/s in volumetric clouds whether it be in the mesh or some kind of texture trick, but I'm having no luck at all. I also need it to be able to be animated.

Using eevee 2.92

I'm looking for a similar effect to these.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). No, you can't really add holes to a 'Volume' in Eevee. All volumes are simplified to simple rectangles unlike in Cycles.

Answer (score 1):

This is not volumetric and this is not exactly the same effect (I'll edit if I find something closer to what you show) but you could do something like that:

[image]

I've created a bezier circle and a cylinder, given the cylinder an *Array* modifier (with *Fit Type > Fit Curve* with the curve as *Curve*) + *Curve* modifier (with a bezier circle as *Curve Object*) + *Subdivision* modifier + *Displace* modifier (with a *Cloud* texture):

[image]

Then I've given 2 or more shapekeys to the cylinder, stretched it so that it deforms, and keyframed the shapekeys:

[image]

Comment: What else did you do, I tried it and all I got was a wiggly mess.

Comment: maybe share your file so that I can see why you failed: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here, I haven't done the shape keys yet. https://pasteall.org/blend/840884b2061341df919927b19959fc44

Comment: For the Array modifier, choose Relative Offset axis > Y, and for the Curve modifier, choose Deform Axis > Y.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm dumb, sorry about that. Just making sure the shape keys are you scaling it.

Comment: for the shape key I deform it, you can also scale it, do it so that it gives the effect you want

Comment: K, thanks. I'll mess with it.

Comment: deform it and see what it gives, use the Proportional Editing option

Comment: K, I'll give it a shot when I get a chance, its getting late where I am.